React Testing Library - mocking event.target.href automatically prepends domain upon click
I have a simple component like so:
const MyButton = ({ onLinkClick ) => {
    const handleClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        onLinkClick({ href: e.target.href, foo: 'bar', baz: 'quz' }
    }

    return (
        <a href='some-url' onClick={handleClick}>Click me</a>
    )
}

And I'm trying to test it like so:
it('calls onLinkClick with right arguments upon click', () => {
    const props { onLinkClick: jest.fn() }

    const mockEvent = {
        preventDefault: () => {}
        target: { href: 'foo.com' }
    }

    render(<MyButton { ...props } />)

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('link'), mockEvent)

    expect(props.onLinkClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(props.onLinkClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        href: mockEvent.target.href,  // Test fails right here
        foo: 'bar',
        baz: 'quz',
    })
})

I am just trying to test that the right properties are passed to the onLinkClick function and one of those properties happen to reference e.target.href.
It expects foo.com but actually receives https://www.example.com/foo.com
Does anyone know what I did wrong?

It looks like if I pass in a fully qualified domain name (including the trailing slash), it works.
const mockEvent = {
    preventDefault: () => {}
    target: { href: 'https://www.example.com/' }
}

Simply using foo.com was being treated as a relative path.
